# Automatically open links in gmail using applescript

Tags: javascript, applescript

I'm attempting to run an AppleScript which looks for new emails by a specific sender in gmail (web) --> open the email --> and open a specific hyperlink within the email defined by a searchTerm.

After many trials and error I found an AppleScript which does the job  using javascript. source: cubemg

The script looks for the sender in the inbox, defined by a searchTerm in a span. It then looks for the searchTerm within an a tag of the email body to get the hyperlink.

```
to clicktagName(thetagName, elementnum)

    tell application "Safari"

        do JavaScript "document.getElementsByTagName('" & thetagName & "')[" & elementnum & "].click();" in document 1

    end tell

end clicktagName





to getInputBytagName(thetag, num)

    tell application "Safari"

        set input to do JavaScript "

document.getElementsByTagName('" & thetag & "')[" & num & "].innerHTML;" in document 1

    end tell

    return input

end getInputBytagName





to clicktag(tagName, num)

    tell application "Safari"

        set input to do JavaScript "

var tagName = '" & tagName & "';

var num = '" & num & "';

var x = document.getElementsByTagName(tagName)[num].click();" in document 1

    end tell

end clicktag


set x to 0

set tagName to "span"

set searchTerm to "email@email.com"

set trialInnerHTML to getInputBytagName(tagName, x)

repeat until tagName = searchTerm

    if trialInnerHTML = searchTerm then

        clicktag(tagName, x)

        exit repeat

    end if

    set x to x + 0

end repeat

delay 0

set x to 0

set tagName to "a"

set searchTerm to "Name of link"

repeat 500 times

    set trialInnerHTML to getInputBytagName(tagName, x)

    if trialInnerHTML = searchTerm then

        clicktag(tagName, x)

        exit repeat

    end if

    set x to x + 1

end repeat
```

This is actually working already. However the script can't continuously run in the background. It needs to run manually. Once the condition is met and the email is found the script stops.

I'm trying to alter the code so that the process can be repeated until a new email is received which matches the searchTerm.

Using the repeat until line: repeat until tagName = searchTerm

However new unread emails that match the search term don't open. The script only works if an email by xx sender is already in the inbox.

Any clues much appreciated.

Thank you